# How to add weight to variable for GAM model?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am running a gam model based on a large dataset with many variables. My response variable is the level of "recruitment" by a herd every fall/autumn. This is calculated by the fawn:female ratio every fall/autumn over a 60 year period.

My problem is that there are many years and study sites where only between 1 - 10 females are recorded. This means that the robustness of the ratio is not trustworthy. For example if one female and one fawn is seen, it has a recruitment of 100%, but if they see one more female, that drops by 50%!

I need to tell the model that years/study sites with smaller sample sizes should be weighted less than those with larger sample sizes as these smaller sample sizes are no doubt affecting the results.

[image]

Above is a table of the females observed every year and a histogram of the same.

My model is as follows:

```
gamFIN <-  gam(Fw.FratioFall 
             ~ s(year)
             + s(percentage_woody_coverage) 
             + s(kmRoads.km2) 
             + s(WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD)  
             + s(d3) 
             + s(WT_DEER_springsurveys)
             + s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi)
             + s(Average_mintemp_winter, BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi)
             + s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi, WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD)
             + s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi, d3)
             + s(YEAR, bs = "re") + s(StudyArea, bs = "re"), method = "REML", select = T,  data = mydata)
```

How might I tell the model to weight my response variable by the sample sizes they are based on.

Answer (score 2):

Do not model this as a ratio for your outcome. Instead model the fawn counts as your outcome and model the female counts via an `offset()` term using logged values on the RHS of the formula. You should be offsetting with the log of the fawn count. So the formula would look like this:

```
   Fawns 
         ~ s(year)
        + all_those_smooth_terms
        + offset( lnFemale_counts)
```

The gam models have an implicit log link which is the reason for the logging of the Female counts.

Edit (Gavin's correct. The default for gam is not a linear link):

```
gamFIN <- gam(FawnFall ~ s(year) + s(percentage_woody_coverage) + s(kmRoads.km2) + 
                s(WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD) + s(d3) + s(WT_DEER_springsurveys) + 
      s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi) + s(Average_mintemp_winter, BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi) + 
      s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi, WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD) + s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi, d3) + 
      s(YEAR, bs = "re") + s(StudyArea, bs = "re") + offset(FemaleFall),
      family="poisson", method = "REML", select = T, data = mydata)
```

Comment: gamFIN <-  gam(FawnFall 
               ~ s(year)
               + s(percentage_woody_coverage) 
               + s(kmRoads.km2) 
               + s(WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD)  
               + s(d3) 
               + s(WT_DEER_springsurveys)
               + s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi)
               + s(Average_mintemp_winter, BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi)
               + s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi, WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD)
               + s(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi, d3)
               + s(YEAR, bs = "re") + s(StudyArea, bs = "re") + offset(FemaleFall), method = "REML", select = T,  data = mydata)

Comment: Right. Hope you have enough data for such a complex model. Each smooth function creates essentially 3 or more terms and you need 10-15 cases for each term for a stable estimate.

Comment: I tried this and the deviance explained dropped and the residuals are all over the place. It is also important to model it as a ratio ecologically as we are looking at recruitment, therefore the number of fawns per female is important

Comment: Using an offset _does_ weight the data estimation process. Look up the use of offsets in Poisson regression where you are more likely to find explanations for the mechanism for the offset weighting.

Comment: Make sure you are using `family = poisson()` in the model or some other distribution suitable for counts. The answer here is the right way to address this with that change; the real response is a count and the offset takes car of the per female part of the ratio. You shouldn't have to transform data like this in a GLM/GAM context and the offset is what allows you to normalize without moving away from the integer count response distribution.

Comment: @GavinSimpson My memory of the default link for `gam` was incorrect. Excellent clarification.